# Eclipse / RSE - cannot open remote files

Tags: php, eclipse

I have installed the latest Eclipse PDT release (Helios) and I'm trying to open remote files using the Remote System Explorer.

Unfortunately, I always get an error "RSEF1002" with the message "Message reported from file system: The system cannot find the specified path". It's really driving me nuts as I can't work with Eclipse anymore because of this error!

I'm using Windows Vista 32bit.

Comment: Are you able to successfully test the connection to the remote machine?  Can you create a new remote project and see if you can hit that location?

Comment: The connection is established successfully but as soon as I'm trying to open a remote file, I get the error message and the remote system path reverts to "Empty List". Sometimes I'm able to open remote files by right-clicking the corresponding folder and selecting "Synchronize Cache". However, this also seems to work only in some cases.

Comment: I am getting `RSEF1002: SUB#0:Sftp: 4: `  in error log. Using Windows 10 64-bit connectting to any linux. I can see files but cannot open them.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before but I may be wrong. I suspect that the network protocol you are trying to access is different from the configuration you made. For example you select datastore instead ssh.

You can change the protocol by right clicking "Sftp Files" of the appropriate remote system and selecting properties. In the configuration box select the appropriate protocol (i.e. ssh.files)